# touchSwipe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to include swipe functionality using `touchSwipe.js`  but i am getting error.

Error:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined**
```

I have div `:#myImageFlow`

have added this in HTML :

```
$.getScript('js/touchSwipe.js');
```

and this function in js file :

```
$("#myImageFlow").swipe({
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        if(direction == 'left') {
            my.MouseWheel.handle(-1);
        } else if (direction == 'right') {
            my.MouseWheel.handle(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where do you define "my.MouseWheel"?

Comment: is my.MouseWheel even defined? is it global? I would start by checking that.